# Better way to quickly find appropriate site?

Tags: feature-request, navigation

When I go to [StackExchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) and want to find the appropriate site for my physics question, I immediately think to use the search box at the top of the page labeled "Search all sites". So, I type in "physics" and I get [119,848 results](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=physics), the first 11 pages of which are mostly from Stack Overflow and Ask Ubuntu.

I have seen that you can find a [listing of all sites by name](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#name), but the way to get to that list and navigate through it to Physics is significantly longer than just typing in "Physics" in the search box.

Would it be a good idea to have sites with names containing the key search words appear first on the list of results?

Comment: You could always just type `keyword.stackexchange.com` in your address bar and see what comes up.

Comment: @ale I could, but someone not as familiar with the URLs might not think of that. In many URLs, you never know if you should type "physics.stackexchange.com" or "stackexchange.com/physics" etc (sorry, I'm on a Mac so it's /physics not \physics). I feel the most intuitive thing for a beginner is the search box at the top of the page, since it is placed so prominently on the page and says "Search all sites"

Answer (score 7):

You can always use the [MultiCollider SuperDropdown™](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange-button) that appears when you click on the Stack Exchange icon on the top bar while you're on any site. Scroll down just a bit, and there's an entry spot that allows you to search the names and descriptions of all the sites on the network:

[image]

Searching "Physics" brings up Physics, and stopping at "Physic" also brings up Physical Fitness and Astronomy, since the latter has the word "astrophysicists" in its description.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, but I can't find it. Can you please upload a full screenshot of where it is? What OS are you using?

Comment: @ThomBlairIII Done.

Comment: Thank you very much! Not to belabor a point, but to me at least that icon seems like a much less intuitive place a newcomer might look compared to the "search all sites" search box.

Comment: This is much simpler than what I've done in the past: bring up the list of all sites and then use my browser to perform a text search. Had I known of *this* method, I would have used it some time ago.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that this can be a problem.

Take HDE's answer, your question, and this example: "quantum mechanics".

- Going to [physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-mechanics) directly provides almost 15K hits.
- Going to the main [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=quantum+mechanics) site doesn't mention physics.SE once in the first few pages.

  Instead it offers less helpful suggestions like: [english.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/) first, and floods the results with [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=quantum+mechanics) (with little more than 1300 results), even favoring [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) with a measly 170 returns and [Quantitative Finance](https://quant.stackexchange.com/search?q=Quantum+mechanics) with fewer than 10 hits).
- Needless to say the the MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ falls silent with zero results.